# Access hash values via database request-esque statements

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have two arrays, each containing any number of hashes with identical keys but differing values:

```
ArrayA = [{value: "abcd", value_length: 4, type: 0},{value: "abcdefgh", value_length: 8, type: 1}]
ArrayB = [{value: "ab", value_length: 2, type: 0},{value: "abc", value_length: 3, type: 1}]
```

Despite having any number, the number of hashes will always be equal.

How could I find the largest :value_length for every hash of a certain type?

For instance, the largest :value_length for a hash with a :type of 0 would be 4. The largest :value_length for a hash with a :type of 1 would be 8.

I just can't get my head around this problem.

It would be great if I could get the answer in the way I described above, in a database request-esque fashion.

Currently, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
# place all :value_length values in an array
flat_A = ArrayA.flatten.map{|h| h[:value_length]} #=> [4,8]
flat_B = ArrayB.flatten.map{|h| h[:value_length]} #=> [2,3]
```

But I don't know how I could compare the parallel results of separate arrays. i.e. (4 with 2, 8 with 3)

```
loop_A = 0
loop_B = 0

flat_A.each do |a|
    flat_B each do |b|
        if loop_A == loop_B
            comparisson_array << a << b

            #something like this I just can't think!!!!             

            comparisson_array.index comparisson_array.max #=> 1
        end
        loop_B += 1
    end
    loop_A += 1 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
ArrayA = [{value_length: 4, type: 0},{value_length: 8, type: 1}]
ArrayB = [{value_length: 2, type: 0},{value_length: 3, type: 1}]
ArrayA.zip(ArrayB).map {
  |a, b| [a[:value_length], b[:value_length]].max
} # => [4, 8]
```

**NOTE**: I assumed that `ArrayA` and `ArrayB` are sorted by `type`.

Comment: Do you reckon you could explain the zip method a bit more? I don't understand the documentation at all. Sorry to sound obtuse, but I really don't.

Comment: Right, done some experimentation. Does it basically join two arrays together into one array? :P

Comment: @Starkers, `a.zip(b)` generate new array containing `[[a[0], b[0]], [a[1], b[1]], ....]` For example, `[1, 2, 3].zip([7, 8, 9])` yields `[[1, 7], [2, 8], [3, 9]]`

Comment: @Starkers, `zip` could be used for more than 2 arrays. Try `[1, 2, 3].zip([7, 8, 9], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'])`